# React not displaying data in table row

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner to React and frontend development in general.
Here is a "simple" code to display a table.

```
function TableHeader() { 
    return (
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    );
  }


function TableDataRow(row, index) {
    return (
        <tr key={index}>
            <td>{row.name}</td>
            <td>{row.job}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}


function TableBody(props) { 
    const characterData = props.characterData;
    return (
        <tbody>
            {characterData.map((row, index) => <TableDataRow row={row} index={index}/>)}
        </tbody>
    );
  }



class Table extends Component {
    render() {
        const { characterData } = this.props;

        return (
            <table>
                <TableHeader />
                <TableBody characterData={characterData} />
            </table>
        );
    }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const characters = [
      {
          'name': 'Charlie',
          'job': 'Janitor'
      },
      {
          'name': 'Mac',
          'job': 'Bouncer'
      },
      {
          'name': 'Dee',
          'job': 'Aspring actress'
      },
      {
          'name': 'Dennis',
          'job': 'Bartender'
      }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="container">
       <Table characterData={characters} />
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The error is as follows:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
>
> Check the render method of `TableBody`. See
>   https://banned-fb.example.com/react-warning-keys for more information.
>       in TableDataRow (at Table.js:30)
>       in TableBody (at Table.js:44)
>       in table (at Table.js:42)
>       in Table (at App.js:28)
>       in div (at App.js:27)
>       in App (at src/index.js:6)

The data rows are empty in the table. I think there is an issue in the call to *TableDataRow*. What is that I am possibly doing wrong?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key thing is just a warning, but you should fix it too, the reason nothing is rendering because you have your component like this:

```
function TableDataRow(row, index) {...}  // WRONG
```

Function Component get just one argument that is props, what you need to do is either:

```
function TableDataRow(props) {
    const {row, index} = props;  // get row and index out of props inside function
    ... 
}
```

#### OR

```
function TableDataRow({ row, index }) {...}  // destructure the props in parameter
```

---

Now About fixing the **key** warning:
Instead of providing `key` to the `<tr>` inside `TableDataRow` you need to provide key to `TableDataRow`, like this:

```
function TableDataRow({ row }) { // you have a little error here too, row should be inside curly braces or use props and get row from props inside the function
  return (
    <tr>  // no need of key
        <td>{row.name}</td>
        <td>{row.job}</td>
    </tr>
  )
}


function TableBody(props) { 
  const characterData = props.characterData;
  return (
    <tbody>
        {characterData.map((row, index) => <TableDataRow row={row} key={index}/>)}  // key should be here
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

Also you should use index as key as last resort (see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for why). If your data comes from `api` every item might have an `id` you can use that as key, or there is maybe something else unique for each character, if not, it's ok to use index.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
function TableHeader() {
  return (
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Job</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  );
}


function TableBody(props) {
  const characterData = props.characterData;

  return (<tbody>
    {characterData.map((row, index) =>
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{row.name}</td>
        <td>{row.job}</td>
      </tr>)}
  </tbody>
  );
}



class Table extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { characterData } = this.props;

    return (
      <table>
        <TableHeader />
        <TableBody characterData={characterData} />
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const characters = [
      {
        'name': 'Charlie',
        'job': 'Janitor'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Mac',
        'job': 'Bouncer'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Dee',
        'job': 'Aspring actress'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Dennis',
        'job': 'Bartender'
      }
    ];

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Table characterData={characters} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Hello;
```

Find your working solution here..

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqgpv5?file=Hello.js)

Comment: For future reference, you can paste the code here with an optional stackblitz link.